# runTaskLater() equivalent on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

With the Bukkit plugin on Android, I'm able to use a simple `runTaskLater()` method in order to execute one method, having it do one action, then having another action run after a set amount of time, however on iOS I'm only aware of the `performSelector:` method.

A nice example of what I'm trying to do would be a fading animation for some text. Say I wanted it to first fade in, then fade out a second after it's reached its peak opacity, at the moment I'm having to use two separate methods for fading in and out, which seems rather inefficient, however I'm not able to come across an example or explanation of how this can be done. This of course could be down to my poor choice of search terms.

How can I delay a chunk of code for a set time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try either of these approaches?

```
const float delayInSeconds = 3.0;
NSString *myObject = @"Hello";

// method 1
[self performSelector:@selector(doSomethingWithObject:) withObject:myObject afterDelay:delayInSeconds];

// method 2
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self doSomethingWithObject:myObject];
});
```

To answer your question about fading a label in and out, try this:

```
label.alpha = 0.0f;
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.f delay:0.f options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
    [label setAlpha:1.f];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.f delay:1.f options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
        [label setAlpha:0.f];
    } completion:nil];
}];
```

Comment: you need a non-zero delay on the second animation as he wants a second of full opacity before the outward fade begins; in my answer I've suggested doing the two things without specifying one as a completion handler but either way works. +1 from me for supplying code.

Comment: @Tommy I don't know if you've read my edited answer, but it uses a completion block, so there is no need for a secondary delay.

Comment: @doctoroder there is a need for a delay. He wants: (i) fade in; (ii) stay the same for one second; (iii) fade out. You've given him code for (i) fade in; (ii) fade out. You're missing the stay the same. EDIT: put another way, he wants it to "fade out a second after it's reached its peak opacity". How many seconds after the text has hit its peak opacity will it begin to fade out with your existing edit?

Comment: @doctoroder I was under the impression that the performSelector's selector parameter was limited to say, the name of another method itself, hence why I currently use that to fire a fade out method, at the end of the fade in method. 

As for 'method 2', I can safely say that I've never seen this used in particular. 

Finally, I like what you've got here with the example of animations, and I'm very thankful for the help that you've provided. I've still got a long way to go but it's good to know I can rely on this community

Comment: @Valon Sure thing. Don't forget to accept this answer if it worked for you.

Comment: @doctoroder I was curious as to, when using 'method 2' as you stated, I could swap out the [] method calling, for a few lines of code that I'd like to run, or would I need to leave it as you've done and have a separate method called?

Comment: @Valon You can do whatever you want within the braces of dispatch_after

Answer (score 1):

doctordoder's answer explains how to schedule a unit of work for later, whether it be a particular method call or a complete closure.

However, reading between the lines on:

> A nice example of what I'm trying to do would be a fading animation
>   for some text. Say I wanted it to first fade in, then fade out a
>   second after it's reached its peak opacity, at the moment I'm having
>   to use two separate methods for fading in and out, which seems rather
>   inefficient, however I'm not able to come across an example or
>   explanation of how this can be done. This of course could be down to
>   my poor choice of search terms.

For that specific example, rather than writing your own code, you should let CoreAnimation do the work for you. The standard observation applies: if you can communicate with the system on exactly the level you're thinking, do so, as it can then optimise exactly for what you want to do. In this case the work will elide with other composition changes, occur safely on a completely separate thread — particularly useful here as otherwise you will have to do your work on the main thread — and has a bunch of guaranteed timing characteristics.

It's a pain discovering it in Apple's documentation but since [`CABasicAnimation`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CABasicAnimation_class/Introduction/Introduction.html) implements [`CAMediaTiming`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CAMediaTiming_protocol/Introduction/Introduction.html%60), that means that it provides `beginTime`. So by building your animation manually and attaching it directly to your `CALayer` via `-addAnimation:forKey:`, you can simultaneously attach the fade-in and the fade-out, with the fade-out specified not to begin for a second plus the time of the first animation, you'll get the whole thing without further contrivance.

Alternatively, use `UIView`'s `+animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:` specifying an appropriate delay to achieve the same thing via the UIKit convenience methods.